# skipping reCaptcha multiple image selections

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have included a google recaptcha in my website. But, I want to skip the multiple image selections . I mean no puzzle should appear to the user. He should be able to directly tick the recaptcha. Is this possible. If so how? Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to remove the CAPTCHA part from the CAPTCHA …? Solving this puzzle _is part of_ the process of determining whether it is a human or a robot. If Google thought they were a human already, then they would not show the puzzle. But they don’t, and so they do show it. That is how reCaptcha _works_ …

Comment: So there is not way to disable it? I got complaints from users that the puzzles are a bit complex, so I wanted to remove it

Comment: Then use a different CAPTHCA solution.  Having the checkbox with no fallback completely defeats the purpose of having a CAPTCHA on your site.

Comment: Supposing you could remove it, it means that if the user is suspected to be a robot you either let him pass because no puzzle and thus the captcha is pointless or block him and then tons of real users will be blocked.

as stepeh.vakil suggests : use a different capcha solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ReCaptcha from Google need to use this *puzzle* to determine whether the user is a robot or not.

If your really want to remove this part you should think about using another CAPTCHA. Find the one that fit your technology.

***[Here](https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-captcha-plugins/)*** is a link that provide different other solution. Some of them use the old *number* or *text* to rewrite.

*NOTE* : It would be better to use the Google ReCaptcha as it is reliable. Tell your users that the Captcha has a security purpose and it is important